# Tablas en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que hacer que la funcion imprima:

```
Funciones    1    2    3    etc
```

Pero imprime:

```
Funciones    1 
Funciones    2 
Funciones    3 
etc
```

Es decir, cada elemento que haya en la lista es un numero del comenzando 1 al n dependiendo de el largo de la misma y la idea es que cada numero sea una columna distinta para luego, debajo poner informacion por cada columna y fila. Como puedo hacer que lo imprima de la manera que yo quiero?

codigo:

```
def analizador_funciones(lista_nombres_funciones):
   for x in range(1,len(lista_nombres_funciones) + 1):
      print("{0:1} \t {1:1}".format("Función", x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás obteniendo ese resultado debido a que está imprimiendo una linea diferente en cada iteración, la idea es que quede todo en una misma linea. Si te fijas en la [referencia de `print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), según la documentación oficial de Python:

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`

El argumento `end` de `print()` que indica que caracter va indicar el final de la impresión por defecto es `"\n"`. Este caracter indica cambio de linea. Por lo tanto, puedes usar otro final para `print()` que no sea un cambio de linea y puede funcionar como separador:

```
def analizador_funciones(lista_funciones):
    print("Función",end = "   ")
    for x in range(1,len(lista_funciones) + 1):
        print("{}".format(x),end = "   ")
```

Hay que notar que se está imprimiendo "Función" antes del bucle, de lo contrario obtendríamos la palabra en cada iteración.

De igual manera también es válido ir añadiendo elementos al string y imprimir un solo string, se vería igual:

```
def analizador_funciones(lista_funciones):
    string = "Función   " 
    for x in range(1,len(lista_funciones) + 1):
        string += "{}   ".format(x)

    print(string)
```

Con ambas manera obtienes el mismo resultado:

```
Función   1   2   3
```

Espero te haya servido.

Answer (score 1):

Sucede que estas imprimiendo en cada iteración "Funcion" y el valor de tu iteración,

lo que debes hacer es imprimir "Funcion" una sola vez seguido de tus valores, podrías hacer un generador de expresion para crear una lista y agrupar todos tus valores, luego un join sería suficiente para unir todos tus valores.

Esta sería una version corta que podría ayudarte:

```
def analizador_funciones(lista_nombres_funciones):
    print("Funciones:", " \t ".join(list(x for x in range(1,len(lista_nombres_funciones) + 1))))
```

o una version extendida un poco mas facil de entender:

```
def analizador_funciones(lista_nombres_funciones):
   functions = []
   for x in range(1,len(lista_nombres_funciones) + 1):
      functions.append(x)
   print("Funciones", " \t ".join(functions)
```

Espero te sea útil.